# Different behaviour of urllib.urlretrieve vs urllib.request.urlretrieve

Tags: python

The issue here is that my code normally checks the library for the correct library with a `try` `except` statement. But in escence, I've noticed that if I open with:

```
fd = urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(out_directory, filename + file_type))
```

I get an `attribute` error which I am handling, but I also get an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

But if I try to correct the attribute error with the following code:

```
fd = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(out_directory, filename + file_type))
```

despite the URL being the same, I don't get the same 403 error. However it seems url cannot be read as I get no output file written. So it looks like it is the 403 problem but with no error message.

So to fix the 403, how can I easily and generically add the headers into the urlretrieve call? Why is the error handling different?

Comment: Why don't you use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)  which provides the same interface in Python 2 and 3?

Comment: @mhawke Looks like that is the only option to sanitize this code.

Comment: It can be done, but it's fiddly to set up the headers - it's a bit of a mess. So, while it's possible to use the standard library, `requests` is _much_ easier to use, it works for both versions of Python, and it supports session handling and HTTP 1.1 (Python 2's urllib supports only HTTP 1.0). I'd add an answer to this question, but `requests` is the way to go, even if you have to write your own file.